# What is $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{x}{1+bx}\right]$ where $x$ is lognormal

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the expected value of $\frac{x}{1+bx}$  where $x$ is lognormal. Note I am not certain that an analytic solution exists. I was not able to do it with a straightforward integral calculation, so I'm wondering if there is some other trick I could use to compute this. Here is the integral (I believe)

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}(1+bx)}e^{-(\ln x -\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}dx
\end{equation}

Note I can find E(1/x) via moments or a symmetry argument or solving the integral via substitution. It's that pesky 1, in the denominator, getting in the way.